# In QML, is there a Conditional Layout that corresponds to the phones orientation?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

So instead of guessing it with something like this:

```
ConditionalLayout 
{
    name: "column"
    when: layouts.width > units.gu(50)
    Column 
    {...
```

It would be something like this:

```
ConditionalLayout 
{
    name: "column"
    when: layouts.landscape == true
    Column 
    {...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [QtQuick.Window][1] API to access **Qt::ScreenOrientation** (requires Qt >= 5.1, 14.04 provides 5.2):

- Qt.PrimaryOrientation: The display's primary orientation.
- Qt.LandscapeOrientation: Landscape orientation, display width is greater than display height.
- Qt.PortraitOrientation: Portrait orientation, display height is greater than display width, rotated 90 degree clockwise relative to landscape.
- Qt.InvertedLandscapeOrientation: Inverted landscape orientation, rotated 180 degrees relative to landscape.
- Qt.InvertedPortraitOrientation: Inverted portrait orientation, rotated 180 degrees relative to portrait.

The following code will modify the layout if a Landscape orientation is detected:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

ConditionalLayout 
{
    name: "column"
    when: Screen.orientation == Qt.LandscapeOrientation
    Column 
    {...
```

Comment: Are conditional layouts not the proper way to do this then? Coming from the ubuntu sample code on layouts, your method is quite different! :)

Comment: Not really, if you read the doc about [ConditionalLayout](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Layouts.ConditionalLayout/) you'll notice that **"Other elements like Screen orientation can also be used to define the layout activation condition"**. So both are independent but ConditionalLayout can of course make use of the QtQuick.Window API. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Your answer perfectly fine, which is why I up-voted it. The reason why I do not accept it, is because I find it is too long and technical for *my tastes*. When I see things such as "text: Screen.logicalPixelDensity.toFixed(2)", without comment to why it is relevant to my answer, or even what it does, the answer starts to feel very broad, and that I may not even meet the pre-requisites to understanding it.

Comment: Let me remove the (long) example in that case and give you a small snippet of code

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more concise. The essential code is there now